# I am making a discord bot in python I am wondering how to check if the user who started the command entered a message using client.wait_for

Tags: python, discord

the title explains basically everything! To elaborate, the user enters !start then the bot asks a question then waits for a response, how do I check if the person who gave the response was the person who entered !start?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a check.

```py
@bot.command(name="start")
async def start(ctx):
    # Send the question.
    await ctx.send("question")
    
    # Make a check to be used in the event
    def check(m):
        # Returns true or false
        return ctx.author.id == m.author.id
    
    # Make a variable so you can use/store the answer
    msg = await bot.wait_for(event, check=check)

    # Do whatever you want the data
    await ctx.send(f"Your answer is: {msg.content}")
```

You can find more data in the docs.

Comment: sorry this is my first time using discord bots, ctx.author.id comes up with an error, any ideas why?

Comment: you can try changing. `ctx.author.id` -> `ctx.message.author.id`